# LoadAllAssetsAtPath is returning an empty array in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to have access to all assets in a specific file in my code.
So I'm using the following line of code:

`Object[] objects = AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetsAtPath("Assets/GameData/Games/01.games");`

When I try to acces to element of the array (with a `foreach` loop for example), the `objects` array appears to be empty.

However there are indeed some assets in this file:

[image]

I also tried to access a specific asset:

```
PKGame game = (PKGame)AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath("Assets/GameData/Games/01.games", typeof(PKGame));
```

But `game` is `null` when I execute the code.

Am I using the correct method here?

Comment: What type of GameObjects are those objects? What's the size of `objects` when you load with `Object[] objects = AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetsAtPath("Assets/GameData/Games/01.games");`?

Comment: The context changed a bit, but the issue is still the same with a folder containing sprites. The array length is 0.

Comment: make sure they are in the right folder. try `Resources` folder.

Answer (score 0):

`LoadAllAssetsAtPath` is a deceiving method name for the actual task that it is performing, which is to load the main asset and sub assets for a specific file. **In other words, it will not load all assets from a folder.**

Some Unity files can have "sub assets" associated with them, and with this method the "main" asset and "sub assets" will all be returned. An example of this is a Maya file that might have meshes and GameObjects associated with it.

If you are trying to load all assets from a path, you have two options:

1. Put your objects into a **Resources** folder and use the [Resources.LoadAll()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.LoadAll.html) method.
2. Use [System.IO.Directory.GetFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.8)